# how to include turtlesim/msg/pose in my ROS2 program?

Tags: compiler-errors, include, ros2

this is the error i keep on getting [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acCjz.png) working out different ways, what could be the possible error?
I can clearly see the topic `turtlesim/pose` and the msg type `turtlesim/msg/pose` in the topic list in terminal but the compile is not detecting the directory and cannot able to include these are the [CMakelist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pniq9.png) and [.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jN9J.png)

what could be the problem?

Comment: why does your include end with a slash?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you posted your code too. Or atleast a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

It is probably a typo, as [starball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball) mentioned in comments.

In any case, You can look at a [working example in git](https://github.com/shoufei403/ros2_galactic_tutorials/blob/43355d5ce6548354ffadb0a23ee71b9d9ff5918c/turtlesim/tutorials/mimic.cpp). specificly:

- you should include it with

```cpp
#include <turtlesim/msg/pose.hpp>
```

- and you can use it like:

```cpp
pose_subscription_ = this->create_subscription<turtlesim::msg::Pose>(
            "turtle1/pose",
            1, std::bind(&SquareMove::pose_callback_, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```